# Added Items multiply (Listbox / Dropdownbox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, dropdownbox

I have a couple of Listboxes, and want to add Items to it.
So I have a Button and a Listbox:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Rows="5"></asp:ListBox>    
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

And I add Items to the Listbox in the C# Code:

```
for (i = 0; i < getSurnameData.countData; i++)
{
     ListBox1.Items.Insert(i, getSurnameData.StringData[i]);  //Writes the Outcome into a Listbox
}
```

The problem is, that if I press the Button, the Page reloads and the Items get added again, and again. This leads to a massive Listbox, the more I press the Button.

Any Ideas how I can prevent that?

Comment: Are the values distinct? If so check if the list already contains the item in question: `if (!ListBox.Items.Contains(getSurnameData.StringData[i])...`

Comment: Thanks rdoubleui, I never thought of that. Got it to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each button click first you should clear the content of list box using below code

```
listbox1.Items.Clear();
```

If it didn't cleared it will append the data to the existing values of listbox.

in your case the for loop is adding values to the listbox
so before the for loop do the coding

```
listbox1.Items.Clear();
for (i = 0; i < getSurnameData.countData; i++)
{
 ListBox1.Items.Insert(i, getSurnameData.StringData[i]);  
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. But when I want to read out the Selected Item and press the Button, it reads out 'null'.

Comment: loading the data in listbox the selected item read in same button press?

Comment: What might happens, is that if I select the Item, and then press the button, it clears the data, re-writes it and de-selects the Item. I just tried to de-bug it, but everything works fine.